# Visual Studio not compiling TypeScript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a Visual Studio project with a structure like so:

[image: Folder structure]

My `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

However, VS isn't compiling the `app.ts` into the `wwwroot` folder.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you check "Compile TypeScript on build" in the Project Properties -> Build?

Comment: It is... I didn't build!  I thought it was continuous rather than on build.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @BanksySan you might be looking for "Compile on save" in Properties > TypeScript Build

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From within **Visual Studio**, Project <kbd>></kbd> Properties <kbd>></kbd> Build <kbd>></kbd> ensure that the "Compile TypeScript on build" is checked:

[image]

Also, in your `tsconfig.json` you should specify a `rootDir` so that **TypeScript** knows where to look for `*.ts` files it should compile:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/",
    "rootDir": "../wwwroot/"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The details are called out on the **TypeScript** page [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

**Don't forget to actually build it.  It isn't a file watcher scenario.**

Comment: Cheers David.  It turned out the missing peice of my puzzle was that I didn't realise that it was triggered on build, I thought it was constantly watching the files.

Comment: Does Visual Studio actually use the settings in tsconfig.json?

Comment: @VernJensen absolutely, if they are omitted then they rely on defaults.

Comment: I don't have this option in my asp.net project

Answer (score 17):

Try adding `"compileOnSave": true` to your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "../wwwroot/"
     },
     "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ],
    "compileOnSave": true
}
```

It should compile every time you save now.

Comment: That did it for me.

Comment: Worked for me too! Note: compilerOptions.noEmit must be removed or set to false for this solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

**It could be a syntax error in the typescript file.**

My solution was to roll back the `.ts` file until it compiled (i.e. the timestamps of typescript and javascript files were identical) and start to change the `.ts` file from there. If the timestamps are not identical after compiling the `.ts` file, then we know it is probably a syntax error. I had to compile after every change and check the timestamp.

The syntax error was unfortunately not shown anywhere so I had to rely on timestamps to determine whether a file was compiled or not.

I had Compile-on-save enabled in Visual Studio 2019

---

Below is an screenshot of FileExplorer where the `.ts` has an error. Notice the difference in timestamps.

[image]

Below is an screenshot of FileExplorer where the `.ts` file is complied into `javascript successfully. Motice the timestamps are identical.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2022, changing the .ts file's Property -> Build Action from "None" to "TypeScript File" did the trick for me.